# Putting two different scroller in a youtube page to make improved custom UI experience

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, html-rendering

Aim: As we scroll the youtube on browsers, the whole page scrolls down, I want to create two scrollers:

1. Left one for video and comment scrolling.
2. Right one for Up next(suggested videos) scrolling.

I found out we can do that with `overflow: scroll;`[shown in this JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shubham27822/wQ6WQ/1165/)

Take example: [Sample Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcJtL7QggTI)

If you inspect these are the two columns:
[image: left and right column div elements]

[image: visual representation of left column]

[image: visual representation of right column]

However, when I apply the style property there (overflow:scroll). Its not applied.

Since Its a dynamic page, I wanted to make a chrome extension that will do this job, but I don't know how to begin?

**Update** : Locally->
[image]

Not working by cut-paste in live page:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a JSfiddle based off the DOM structure of the YouTube page. I simulated the dynamically loading content with some random images.

Basically YouTube has an `overflow-y: scroll` on the `body` element. Therefore when you try to add an `overflow-y: scroll` to any children of `body`, there is technically no content to overflow since the `body` has already handled it.

So the first step is to stop the body from overflowing. For this you can set `overflow-y: hidden` on body. Next you will notice there is still no scroll on the columns. This is because the columns height is expanding to fit the dynamically loaded content. So you need to force the two columns to have a fixed height. Then when the dynamically added content exceeds the height, it will overflow and scroll bar will appear. To fix the height you can either explicitly set the height of `#primary`/`#secondary`, or the parent `#columns`, or any ancestor node up the tree and just inherit the height.

Anyway so these are the fiddles: [Before](https://jsfiddle.net/drabbitzz/avx3s6rf/5/) and [After](https://jsfiddle.net/drabbitzz/6j7dgr0m/).

**UPDATE:** Adding youtube comments to the `#secondary` column.

[image]

Comment: Thanks man for the answer, btw couldn't upvote your answer because of my low reputation, Yeah this really worked, fixing the height was the key, it worked!  Suppose the primary column has a <ytd-comments> element for all the comments and I want to cut paste it to the secondary column so that right column scrolls all the comments without scrolling down the video, but when I am pasting the <ytd-comments> element in the secondary column It didn't show up?

Comment: @shubhamagarwal no worries man, you might still be able to select best answer, but not exactly sure. Youtube uses a JavaScript library called Polymer to generate the DOM. So when you look at it the end result it might be difficult to understand and manipulate cause the structure is weird and there's a ton of elements and styles everywhere, most of which weren't explicitly coded but are being created and handled by Polymer. Anyway check out the image I put in the post, I deleted all the related video elements so the column is just comments.

Comment: thanks man for the response. Yeah If I cut paste the <ytd-comments in the live page it wouldn't work, but is working if I download the whole html page. Did you also do the same? If yes then maybe this happens because of this interruption by Polymer that you said.

Comment: What I basically trying to do is to create 2 scrollers one will be for video and moving comments to second  column which will have a button to switch between comments scrolling and video scrolling, like what Facebook do.

Comment: nah I didn't download the file, just did a cut and paste into the items div through the browser console. If you want tabs I'd imagine you have to wrap the existing related video elements in a div, then wrap the comments in a div. So under items you will have only 2 top level divs, one for each tab. Haven't tested it but it should work, let me know how you go.

Comment: Actually my comments are not shown because when I cut the <ytd-comments> there is content div containing the loaded comments but as I pasted in the secondary column's item div as you did, my content div becomes empty. I don't know why that's happening. I have attached the images above.